# Blender suddenly not baking tangent space normals correctly

Tags: normals

When trying to bake a normal map I would get very wrong results. I noticed dark areas and big discrepancies across UV seams. It wasn't like this last time I tried, a couple of days ago. After poking around I understood that the issue was with the tangent space.

[image: A cube with a plane above it, the plane showing a normal map of the cube.]

Here's a test setup. The plane takes normals from the cube, and one UV island is rotated 45 degrees.

[image: A cube with a plane above it, one part of the plane has incorrect normals.]

Here's how it looks when rendered. As you can see, the normals on the rotated island are off.

Furthermore, it seems that if I rotate the islands in increments of 90 degrees the normal map retains the exact same colors regardless of the UV islands rotation. This obviously becomes wrong when rendered as the tangent vector is different, but the colors don't change to reflect this.

With a complex unwrapped model the islands are at all kinds of rotations, and I get this:

[image: A render of a face with patchy, incorrect normals.]

Here is my render setup, I haven't touched any of the tangent space swizzles from their default.
[image: The Blender bake panel at a standard selected to active setup.]

I'm very surprised by this, as it just suddenly appeared, and seems to be consistent when restarting blender, opening a new project etc. I opened an old project where I had baked normals and tried to bake them again in there without changing any settings, the error remained. I'd be very thankful for any help, as normal baking is an important part of my workflow.

Cheers!

Comment: There are a few potential problems here, including some that are Blender's fault, but the first thing that sticks out to me is that your normal map is being read in sRGB.  With Blender's treatment, that's a strict no-go.  Bake and read your normal map image as non-color data.  However, that wouldn't explain "Furthermore, it seems that if I rotate the islands in increments of 90 degrees the normal map retains the exact same colors regardless of the UV islands rotation" which is a big problem, but not one that I've seen-- any kind of demo would be appreciated.

Comment: Thank you Nathan, it seems like that did it! The tricky part was that the color space option was grayed out as you can see in the screenshot, I had to save the texture externally in order to get access to it. Just out of curiosity, how do you _bake_ as non-color data, I don't see any such option?

Comment: You can set the color space before you bake, on the image texture node, which the bake then follows.  I believe it's grayed out because the image texture node is duplicated.